# line intersecting rectangle without usig Similarity

Tags: geometry

a line intersected Segments AB and BC of a triangle if the distance of point A from line equal to 7 and line from B equal to 5 and line from C equal  to 4. then find the distance of point D from the line.
[image]

My Attempt:I cannot do any thing special but I solved it completely using Similarity of triangle and found the answer 16.but Similarity isn't allowed in this question

note:Similarity is not allowed.

Comment: I can't make a picture from geogebra .maybe drawing a picture helps a lot

Comment: I put a picture maybe helps you

Comment: No it isn't parallel with AC it is a random line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AC$ and $BD$ have the same midpoint, $M$. By Thales' theorem the distance of $M$ from the line $l$ has to be $\frac{4+7}{2}$. On the other hand, it has to be $\frac{d(D,l)-5}{2}$, too, so $d(D,l)=16$.

Comment: Let a, b, c be the given perpendiculars and d the required perpendicular. a + b + c = d always.